# issett button is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

hi i have made a registration form using jquery and php which validates the user input whilst they are entering data, when all the information is correct i want to allow the user to submit the form.  i am going to do this by writing an if statement which checks if the error messages are empty and if the submit button has been clicked. at the moment i am just testing my isset button and its no working and i have no idea why.

Comment: You don;t send a value named `reg`

Comment: can you provide your full html form??

Comment: iv posted my full form code

Comment: @percy3872 - check your post values (what you send to php script), there is no $reg var, as John mentioned. You will have to add it, or to check something else, eg. fname....

Comment: do i need to add a reg var in my jquery

Answer (score 0):

It seams like you are having problems with your javascript validation. Here is a sample validator using jquery.

```js
/*Intercepts the form submision*/
$('#myform').submit(function(e) {
  /*sets send to true*/
  var send = true;
  /*foreach required element*/
  $('.required').each(function() {
    /*check if input is valid*/
    if (!$(this).val()) {
      /*if not valid, don't send and mark red*/
      send = false;
      $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
    } else {
      /*if valid, take away mark*/
      $(this).css('background-color', 'none');
    }
  });
  /*if don't send, prevent sending*/
  if (!send) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id='myform' method='post'>
  <input name='test' class='required' />
  <input type='submit' />
</form>
```